# Able to create Hive table using JSON objects but not all objects are being captured into respective attribute

Tags: json, hadoop, hive

I am able to create a Hive table using JSON objects but not all objects are being captured into their respective attribute. A few are absorbed into one attribute.  How do I break out the remaining attributes into their respective "columns".

Most of the below fields do get put into table but screen_name, name and location are grouped with a number of other objects into retweeted_status and user.  Retweeted_status and user appear to be a long JSON string that also needs to be broken out into a table. Would i need to perform another activity like the below, and if so, how could i do that?  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks,

Here is my script,

```
CREATE TABLE Bank_F001 (json string);
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'banking-1-26-16.txt' INTO TABLE Bank_F001;

create table Bank_F001_table as
select
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.text') as text,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.in_reply_to_user_id') as in_reply_to_user_id,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.id') as id,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.favorite_count') as favorite_count,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.coordinates') as coordinates,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.id_str') as id_str,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.location') as location,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.lang') as lang,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.indices') as indices,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.type') as type,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.hashtags') as hashtags,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.user_mentions') as user_mentions,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.screen_name') as screen_name,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.name') as name,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.in_reply_to_screen_name') as in_reply_to_screen_name,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.retweet_count') as retweet_count,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.favorited') as favorited,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.retweeted_status') as retweeted_status,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.user') as user,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.followers_count') as followers_count,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.statuses_count') as statuses_count,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.description') as description,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.geo_enabled') as geo_enabled,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.favourites_count') as favourites_count,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.created_at') as created_at,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.time_zone') as time_zone,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.listed_count') as listed_count,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.in_reply_to_user_id_str') as in_reply_to_user_id_str
from Bank_F001;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... in case you're interested... :)
Basically a bunch of my attributes were nested in the user attribute as an object.
I used the following code to break it out... ".user.location"

```
create table Bank_F001_table as
select
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.text') as text,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.in_reply_to_user_id') as in_reply_to_user_id,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.id') as id,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.favorite_count') as favorite_count,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.coordinates') as coordinates,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.id_str') as id_str,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.user.location') as location,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.lang') as lang,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.indices') as indices,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.type') as type,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.hashtags') as hashtags,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.user_mentions') as user_mentions,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.user.screen_name') as screen_name,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.user.name') as name,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.in_reply_to_screen_name') as in_reply_to_screen_name,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.retweet_count') as retweet_count,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.favorited') as favorited,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.retweeted_status') as retweeted_status,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.user') as user,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.followers_count') as followers_count,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.statuses_count') as statuses_count,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.description') as description,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.geo_enabled') as geo_enabled,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.favourites_count') as favourites_count,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.created_at') as created_at,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.time_zone') as time_zone,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.listed_count') as listed_count,
    get_json_object(Bank_F001.json, '$.in_reply_to_user_id_str') as in_reply_to_user_id_str
from Bank_F001;
```